# How to get all instances of a class?

Tags: powershell

My knowledge of classes is relatively new. But I want to output all objects/instances of a class with powershell. Is this even possible? Here is an example of how I create two objects of the class Computer.

```
Class Computer {
    [String]$Name
    [String]$Description
    [String]$Type

}

$NewComputer = New-Object 'Computer'
$NewComputer.Name = 'ultra1'
$NewComputer.Description = 'Lenovo Yoga 900'
$NewComputer.Type = 'Ultrabook' 

$NewComputer = New-Object 'Computer'
$NewComputer.Name = 'ultra2'
$NewComputer.Description = 'Lenovo Yoga X1'
$NewComputer.Type = 'Ultrabook'
```

Now I want to output both objects, how can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "output". What would the desired output look like?

Comment: As a side note: you may want to avoid using typographic quotes in code. While they work most of the time I did encounter situations where they did cause problems.

Comment: I just want to address all objects of the class and view their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your comment *"if there is a possibility to get the objects of a class without putting them into a collection"*, I think what you want to do is to create new `Computer` objects using your class and later on use these objects as separate variables.

For easier creation, I'd suggest you add a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-6#constructor) to the class, so you can create the objects in a single line:

```
Class Computer {
    [String]$Name
    [String]$Description
    [String]$Type

    # add a constructor
    Computer(
        [string]$n,
        [string]$d,
        [string]$t
    ){
        $this.Name = $n
        $this.Description = $d
        $this.Type = $t
    }
}

# now create the computer objects
[Computer]$pcUltra1 = [Computer]::new('ultra1','Lenovo Yoga 900','Ultrabook')
[Computer]$pcUltra2 = [Computer]::new('ultra2','Lenovo Yoga X1','Ultrabook')

# show what you have now
$pcUltra1
$pcUltra2
```

Output:

> ```
> Name   Description     Type     
> ----   -----------     ----     
> ultra1 Lenovo Yoga 900 Ultrabook
> ultra2 Lenovo Yoga X1  Ultrabook
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: btw, you don't need that constructor: `[Computer]@{Name='ultra1'; Description='Lenovo Yoga 900'; Type='Ultrabook'}`.  The typecasting system is incredibly powerful :)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
Class Computer {
    [String]$Name
    [String]$Description
    [String]$Type

}

# a collection of computers
$computers =@()

$NewComputer = New-Object 'Computer'
$NewComputer.Name = ‘ultra1’
$NewComputer.Description = ‘Lenovo Yoga 900’
$NewComputer.Type = ‘Ultrabook’ 

# append a computer to teh collection
$computers += $NewComputer

$NewComputer = New-Object 'Computer'
$NewComputer.Name = ‘ultra2’
$NewComputer.Description = ‘Lenovo Yoga X1’
$NewComputer.Type = ‘Ultrabook’ 

# append a computer to teh collection
$computers += $NewComputer

# this outputs each of the computers
$computers

# or you can format the data in a table
$computers | Format-Table -AutoSize

# or in a list
$computers | Format-List *

# or as json
$computers | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not  the hoped result i'm looking for, actually I also write all objects in an array. But I am interested in the principle if there is a possibility to get the objects of a class without putting them into a collection.

Comment: @jeremiaskühnis Then why not use different variables for each computer you are creating using your class?? `$pcUltra1 = New-Object 'Computer'; $pcUltra2 = New-Object 'Computer'` etc.

Comment: yes i already did that, sorry for my perhaps not clear question....i want to know if there is a method to read the objects of a class without a "workarround" like putting them in Collections or use different variables. 

Something like  

get-classObjects -class "computer"

would be nice ;-)

Comment: @jeremiaskühnis You can use `Get-Variable` and reflectively look at the object types, but if your object loses its binding (for example, you re-assign a name), that won't work.  The only way to make it work with certainty is to create a static collection on your class and in your constructor, add that object to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't re-bound any names, you can do the following:

```
Get-Variable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value |
    Where-Object { $_.GetType().Name -eq 'Computer' }
```